# Is there a word for misusing or adding letters to words/names?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, orthography, errors

Some people add or change letters that aren't in a word or name, i.e., "Simonese" cat instead of "Siamese" cat, and French "provinincial" furniture instead of French "provincial" furniture. Also adding letters in the middle of a name, such as "Stolperman" instead of "Stolpman."  Is there a word for such misuse of words/names?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe ***epenthesis***, which Wiki describes as "the addition of one or more sounds to a word, especially to the interior of a word". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis).

This might not be exactly what you're looking for though, since from what I can tell this is taken to be primarily a phonetic phenomenon.

For example, [this site](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/schemes.html) on rhetorical schemes claims that a poet might use *visit**at**ing* over *visiting* (in speech *and* orthography) in order to preserve their meter.